# Wait to Promise Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

First of all I want to explain that I have read a lot of answers, and I understand that it's wrong to block the thread to wait a response. But I have an issue that is not that simple to solve.

I have an advanced project, where I have a function on a session service that is `getAuthenticationKey():string` I have used it a lot from differents parts of the code (to call rest functions, etc.), and I made it as an ordinary function because I thought that this value will be there or not.

Now we have made some changes, and the `getAuthenticationKey` will have to call a rest function to refresh the key if it's necessary.

So the problem is that I understand that the best way to do that is to make a promise and refactor the whole project, but this is too expensive in terms of hours, because I have to make promises for that function and all others that depends of that function (almost all the application), and considering that the refresh is a fast operation and is called once a day or a week, there is any way to fix this without refactoring all the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably keep your code as it is, just add a periodic checker (`setInterval(...)`) that will update the `authenticationKey` if necessary. If you know the lifetime of the key, you can just use `setTimeout(...)` instead of periodic checking.

Comment: I have to refresh the key within the getAuthenticationKey, so I have to wait for the new key in the function, there is no other way to wait for the response?

Comment: You could use a synchronous XhrRequest, but it has been deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests That way you could avoid using Promise. Maybe if you wrote why you cannot refresh the auth key in background, it could help with finding a solution.

Comment: In fact I need that the `getAuthenticationKey` returns a valid key (check it against a rest operation) without making the promise. So I don't have to refactor the whole project. If I had known that I will have to check the validity when I create the `getAuthentitacionKey` function I would have done with a promise, but now is a nightmare to make a refactor.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using a Resolver, since I check the authentication when a page is loaded. In the resolver I check the auth against a rest service and store the result in a service.